# AC Voltage Sensing using Arduino Uno

Tags: arduino-uno, analogread, hardware, voltage

Is it possible to sense AC Voltage using analog input for Arduino Uno or can it only read DC?

I mean I've tried connecting an AC voltage source to analog and I'm reading some numbers. However, I don't know if these numbers are actually AC voltage values or something else.

Ultimately I’m trying to find the avg voltage value for a given time duration. I know that analogRead ( ) gives ADC values. However, in my block of code, I have the conversion ratio of 1023/5 to get a good estimate of the voltage. However, I’m not too sure if Arduino analog sensing is suited for AC voltage? I’m using it to sense voltages generated by piezoelectric PVDF film and the frequency is pretty high. All I want is to use avg. voltage value to calculate electrical energy produced by the PVDF film.

Comment: the Arduino can read voltage at its analog input pin ... it takes time to convert the voltage to a numetic value ... if the voltage changes by a large amount during the conversion, then the result will not be accurate ... it can also change do quickly, that the change will not be detected

Comment: what is the frequency of the signal that you are trying to digitize?

Comment: Do you want a [RMS value](https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/accircuits/rms-voltage.html) or to record the values of the waveform (eg. peak)?

Comment: @jsotola: Re “_if the voltage changes by a large amount during the conversion, then the result will not be accurate_”: That's not quite true. The ADC uses a sample-and-hold front-end which is actually pretty fast. Once sampled, the input voltage can change without disturbing the ongoing conversion. You get an accurate reading of the input voltage _at the time of sampling_. Obviously, a rapidly changing signal rises the issues of Nyquist frequency and aliasing, but these are completely unrelated to conversion accuracy.

Comment: You have to be _a lot_ more specif if you want any kind of useful answer. What do you mean by the frequency being “_pretty high_”? What are the typical amplitude and DC offset? Re “_I’m trying to find the avg voltage_”: the easiest way to get the average voltage is to put a low-pass filter in front of the ADC.

Answer (score 0):

The AC voltage that you are trying to measure is about 50/60Hz depending on where you live. And the maximum effective sampling rate for a regular Arduino ADC is 9615Hz. This means you're not going to experience any aliasing as the sampling rate is well above the `2 * Signal Frequency`.

The values that are coming out of `analogRead()` are raw ADC values which you need to do, further calculation on if you want to have a correct voltage reading.

Comment: You have to set the ADC to auto-trigger if you want 9,615 Hz sampling rate. With `analogRead()` you get at most 8,929 Hz (112 µs/sample).

Comment: Ultimately I’m trying to find the avg voltage value for a given time duration. I know that analogRead ( ) gives ADC values. However, in my block of code, I have the conversion ratio of 1023/5 to get a good estimate of the voltage. However, I’m not too sure if Arduino analog sensing is suited for AC voltage? I’m using it to sense voltages generated by piezoelectric PVDF film and the frequency is pretty high. All I want is to use avg. voltage value to calculate electrical energy produced by the PVDF film.

Comment: so it is not mains AC with 50 Hz as the answer assumes

Comment: that is correct